# How to built Ubuntu Server as automation testing server

Tags: docker, selenium, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu Server. I want to use it as remote testing server. My question: can I install and configure docker, selenium grid, chrome and firefox on same machine? Can I use one machine as hub and node? And can I install chrome to run my test cases on ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just remember to download and set the path to the web drivers for each browser.

Comment: Even If in my code I use WebDriverManager dependency, am I still need path to web driver?

Comment: Well, most likely the path you have sent in you development computer is much different to the ones in the server but it's not a big deal it's just about getting the drivers to the server, find the path where they are, and setting them in your settings